# How many numbers between 0 and n satisfy bitwise property i&y==i?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

**Here i is a number between 0 and n 
And y is any random number**

```
//brute force
//say y is 49
count=0;
for(int i=0;i<=49;i++){
    if((i&y)==i)
        count++
}
cout<<count;
```

Also I would like to know what are those numbers ?

Comment: why not cout << i ?

Comment: I want to know if there is any efficient way to compute the "count".

Comment: think about the condition where the bits in i are unchanged when `anding` with another bit, no need to brute force

Comment: As @alain explained you just count how many bits in `y` set to 1 and your number is 2 in power of that count

Answer (score 3):

Let ***b*** be the number of set bits in ***y***.

Then,

***2<sup>b</sup>***

is the number of numbers that satisfy the property.

The numbers are those for which all bits that are not set in ***y*** are also not set.

Comment: I think you have missed some details of the assignment. The influence of n is not covered by your formula. Example where it does not work: For y==192==128+64 we find b=2.  The number predicated by your formula is 2*2==4. So by your formula, 4 numbers should match. 0&192==0. That is one matching number. Which other 3 numbers in the range from 0..49 also match the described condition?

Comment: Yes, I assumed `n >= y`.

Comment: And is that an assumption guaranteed by the assignment?